# Why would dropping down a populated combo box crash a form?

Tags: c#, combobox, nullreferenceexception, crash-reports, dropdownbox

I've got a pair of comboboxes that are populated like so:

```
private void PopulateDeptCombox()
{
    try
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached FrmInventory.PopulateDeptCombox");
        List<String> depts = hhsdbutils.GetDeptItems();

        foreach (String dept in depts)
        {
            comboBoxsDept.Items.Add(dept);
            comboBoxeDept.Items.Add(dept);
        }

        if (comboBoxsDept.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            comboBoxsDept.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        if (comboBoxeDept.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            comboBoxeDept.SelectedIndex = comboBoxeDept.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format(
                "{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From FrmInventory.PopulateDeptCombox(): {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
}
```

GetDeptItems() simply returns a few items for now:

```
List<string> IHHSDBUtils.GetDeptItems()
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached SQliteHHSDBUtils.GetDeptItems");
    List<String> depts = new List<String> { "dept 1", "dept 2", "dept 3", "Test dept" };
    // TODO: Replace this test data
    return depts;
}
```

This form was crashing when I first opened it until I enclosed PopulateDeptCombox() in a try..catch block. It no longer crashes *right away*, but it still records an NRE in the log file:

```
Date: 3/21/2009 1:41:27 AM
Message: Reached FrmInventory.PopulateDeptCombox

Date: 3/21/2009 1:41:27 AM
Message: From FrmInventory.PopulateDeptCombox(): NullReferenceException; Inner Ex: ; Stack Trace:    at 

HHS.FrmInventory.PopulateDeptCombox()
   at HHS.FrmInventory..ctor(String inventoryName, String siteNum, Boolean allowNewItems)
   at HHS.frmNewInventory.buttonOK_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog(IntPtr hwnModal)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at HHS.frmMain.menuItemFILE_NewInventory_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc(Control ctlThis, WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()
```

...but ignores the NRE and soldiers on (acts like it doesn't notice the NRE).

Then, though, if I click comboBoxsDept to check what items it contains, it first "hourglasses" for a spell, then it drops down, showing the items I expect to see -- but only for an eyeblink -- then the form crashes. The "post mortem" (log file) shows the NRE above, plus this at the end of the log file:

```
Date: 3/21/2009 1:42:08 AM
Message: Reached FrmInventory.BarcodeReader_ReadNotify

Date: 3/21/2009 1:42:08 AM
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.NullReferenceException: NullReferenceException
   at HHS.FrmInventory.BarcodeReader_ReadNotify(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.TASK.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InvokeAll()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()
```

So there's yet another NRE, related to the barcode scanning code; this code is NRE-crazy for some reason. I have other forms with the same barcode scanning setup code, yet they don't act like this. Everything is fine until I scan a value and then drop down comboBoxsDept.

How could a populated combobox elicit an NRE?

### UPDATE

If I first scan something into the barcode-scannable textbox, the crash is prevented. If I go straight to the dropdown, it crashes. So it's apparently some oddity/macabreness with the barcode scanning code.

BTW, this was my last question of the year; don't drink too much spicy V8 tonight.

### UPDATE 2

Answer to Grant Winney: Here is my overloaded constructor (the one that's called):

```
public FrmInventory(string inventoryName, string siteNum, bool allowNewItems)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached FrmInventory's overloaded constructor");
    InitializeComponent();

    _siteNum = siteNum;
    _allowNewItems = allowNewItems;
    _invName = inventoryName;
    invFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(HHSUtils.GetGeneratedINVFileName(_siteNum));
    recordDate = HHSUtils.ConvertDateTimeToSQLiteFormat(DateTime.Now);
    comboBoxUPC_PLU.SelectedIndex = 0;
    HookupHandlers();
    PopulateDeptCombox();
    PopulateSubdeptCombox();
    SetRequiredControls();
    textBoxUPC_PLU.Focus();
}
```

### UPDATE 3

This ended up being the "culvert":

```
private void textBoxUPC_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmVerify.textBoxUPC_LostFocus");
    this.DisposeBarcodeReaderAndData();
}

private void DisposeBarcodeReaderAndData()
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
FrmInventory.DisposeBarcodeReaderAndData");
    // If we have a reader
    if (this.barcodeReader != null)
    {
        // Disable the reader
        this.barcodeReader.Actions.Disable();
        // Free it up
        this.barcodeReader.Dispose();
        // Indicate we no longer have one
        this.barcodeReader = null;
    }

    // If we have a reader data
    if (this.barcodeReaderData != null)
    {
        // Free it up
        this.barcodeReaderData.Dispose();
        // Indicate we no longer have one
        this.barcodeReaderData = null;
    }
}
```

Once I commented out the call to *DisposeBarcodeReaderAndData()* -- making that method dead code -- the sun came out, the birds started to sing, they hung the jerk that invented work, and dropping down no longer resulted in a crash.

### UPDATE 4

The problem came back, dad-blast it! I had to move some of my constructor code to the form's Load() event to get it to straighten up and fly right.

Comment: it looks ike it might be a silent NRE.  Add a log entry to the *end* of the ctor like "ctor Completed" and see if it gets logged.  If not you have a silent NRE,